# How to derive following thermodynamic relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'd would like to derive the following

$$\bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg)_T = T \bigg(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\bigg)_V - p$$

What I know is that the internal energy $U$ is a function of temperature and volume.  Hence, a small change in $U$ can be related to changes in $T$ and $V$ by

$$dU =\bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\bigg)_V dT + \bigg(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg)_T dV$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: you need the first law and maxwells relations.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. The First Law is $dU = TdS - PdV$.
2. Write $S$ as a function of $T$ and $V$ and take its differential.
3. Use a certain [Maxwell relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations).